# Refresh Bootstrap Treeview programmatically

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, treeview

I have a Bootstrap tree view which binds to a json array..

```
 $('#tree').treeview({data: data,
           onNodeSelected: function(event, data) {

            $m.nodeSelected(event,data);
          }});
```

And the array that binded to the treeview is..

```
var data = [
    {
      "text": "Parent1",
      "selectable": "false",
      "nodeType": "main",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "text": "Child1",
          "typeId": "aa2d4ea9-bfad-4a5b-8794-994e7e482808",
          "nodeType": "sub"
        },
        {
          "text": "Child2",
          "typeId": "e01bd0cb-c93b-40f9-be44-be67f20668aa",
          "nodeType": "sub"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "Parent2",
      "selectable": "false",
      "nodeType": "main",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "text": "Child1",
          "typeId": "a0256aa3-b2ef-53d7-1270-a5029e7138ce",
          "nodeType": "sub"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Here is what I need..

I need to add a new child node / remove a existing child node from the treeview datasource and refresh it.

I've tried but unable to find a solution.

Comment: Why do you want to `refresh` it ?

Comment: I'm adding new nodes to it's datasource

Comment: Then they should be added without refresh..

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call:

```
$('#tree').treeview({data: data,
     onNodeSelected: function(event, data) {
        $m.nodeSelected(event,data);
     }
});
```

again when you have changed the `data`variable:

example: https://jsfiddle.net/k8m911u9/1/

Answer (score 2):

Thi is possible in development version: https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview/tree/develop
there is added metods for add, delete, update node

Comment: $('#tree').treeview(true).removeNode([]); // refresh hack